# What more uses are there for dragon parts?

Tags: mythical-creatures, dragons

I read this article that tries to describe all things one could do with the body parts and blood of the dragon:

[The Uses of Dragon Parts in Mythology and Folklore](https://mythenthusiast.wordpress.com/2019/03/05/the-uses-of-dragon-parts-in-mythology-and-folklore/)

Does anyone here know of other uses of dragon parts that are not mentioned in this article?

Comment: Really spicy bologna.

Comment: Funny side note from WorldBuilding.SE: [How to butcher your dragon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/63016/28789)

Comment: Dragon liver can cure a cold, dragon powder grows hair. With dragon blood you'll never grow old. Dragon cartilage keeps you thin, dragon fat is for burns, a dragon tear will clear up your skin.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTMe5p_eTZg

Answer (score 2):

Note: Some of these uses were mentioned in the article you brought, but about different body parts.

**Dragon blood**

According to [Into The Wonder](https://intothewonder.wordpress.com/tag/dragons-blood/):

> Lifespan Extender. Probably goes very closely with the invulnerability.

> General Cure-All. On the island of Socotra, dragon’s blood is used as a cure-all for practically everything: fevers, kidney stones, wounds, tumors, respiratory and gastrointestinal complaints, etc. In ancient times, Greco-Roman naturalists such as Pliny the Elder and Dioscorides discussed the curative properties of this substance.

> Magic Enhancer. Those involved with Wicca, neopaganism, hoodoo, and other practices claim that burning powdered dragon’s blood as  an incense can increase the potency of spells or rituals related to protection, banishing, prosperity, luck, love, and fertility.

> Coloring Agent. Dragon’s blood is also used as a dye, ink, or painting pigment. Socotrans use it to dye wool. Neopagan, Wiccan, Hoodoo, and other practitioners say dragon’s-blood ink can be used for writing spells, runes, magical seals, etc.

> Varnish. Dragon’s blood resin has been used to coat and stain wooden objects for centuries. In the eighteenth century, it was especially sought as a varnish for violins. Similarly, cinnabar was used in ancient Japan and elsewhere to lacquer both wooden and clay vessels.

> Mouthwash. This is another use to which Socotrans put dragon’s blood. Dissolved in water and gargled, it can serve as an astringent, a stimulant, and even a kind of toothpaste.

According to [Mugglenet](https://www.mugglenet.com/2019/05/12-real-life-uses-of-dragons-blood/) (real uses, not Harry Potter ones):

> Perfume: Dragon’s blood has a strong earthy scent and makes for an excellent perfume, both on its own or mixed with other scents.

> Ink: Due to the bright red color of the sap, dragon’s blood can easily be turned into equally vibrant ink. Unlike actual blood, dragon’s blood will retain its bright color after drying. It’s easy to make too. All that’s needed is ground-up dragon’s blood resin, gum arabic, and either a water or alcohol base.

> Stop bleeding: In addition to being an antiviral, taspine is a coagulant, which means that when placed upon bleeding wounds, it will encourage the blood to clot and help stop the bleeding.

According to [Healthline](https://www.healthline.com/health/dragons-blood#researched-benefits):

> Antimicrobial: Dragon’s blood may offer some protection against or even kill pathogens like bacteria, fungi, and viruses.

> Anti-inflammatory: Some studies have also revealed antioxidant potential in dragon’s blood. This indicates some anti-inflammatory properties, confirmed in another 2017 study.

> Antidiabetic: Though research isn’t complete, there are signs dragon’s blood could support diabetes treatment or prevention.

> Anticancer: Research related to dragon’s blood and cancer is in its early stages. There may be anti-tumor potential in dragon’s blood.

**Dragon bones**

According to [Circle of the Dragon](http://www.blackdrago.com/topics/parts.htm):

> The Chinese believe in "old ghosts", which could haunt a person. Among other things, dragon bone was able to heal this "spiritual ailment".

> It was also believed to help epilepsy in children, cough, certain abdominal problems, heart problems, several gastrological problems, and even help cure vaginal discharge.

According to [TopTenz](https://www.toptenz.net/top-10-creative-uses-bones.php):

> They were ground and consumed as treatment for a variety of ailments, such as dizziness, leg cramps, dysentery, internal swellings, and malaria.

**Dragon teeth**

According to [Circle of the Dragon](http://www.blackdrago.com/topics/parts.htm):

> Dragon teeth were used to treat what we would call today psychological problems. Madness, certain kinds of spasms, epilepsy, and the inability to catch breath were all treated by dragon's teeth.

> Lengthening a person's life span was said to come about from these teeth, too.

**Dragon body in general**

According to a [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/mythology/comments/ek822y/is_anyone_aware_of_other_uses_for_parts_of_a/fd80jgo?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) which brought [Woden's Nine Herbs Charm](https://heorot.dk/woden-9herbs.html):

> A worm came creeping, he tore a man in two then Woden took 9 Glory-Twigs, struck the adder then, that it flew apart into 9 (bits). There brought about the apple and poison, that she [the adder] would never enter a house.

Meaning, either a cure against poisons in general as suggested by the comment or just against snake-bites, as suggested by the poem's notes.